# Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start and a child container failed during start

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am using eclipse as Java EE IDE and tomcat v9.0 and i m working on a web app. So, on running the tomcat server using eclipse the ide is showing "Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start.". I tried all possible solutions present on online sites but none of them worked for me. So, if anyone have solution, help me in getting rid off this error.

[image: Error Image 1]

[image: Error Image 2]

Comment: the root error is the illegal argument exception - 'more than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found'. I dont know much about spring, so maybe have look at your config to see if you defined that twice?

Comment: thnku, the problem is resolved now